# pass boolean state to multiple of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**The expected**
I want to put a loading state in the content of tab, whenever user clicked on the tab title to switch tab, a flag is passed down through children.

**The problem**
I have this App component, I fake its api call using a setTimeout

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: false,
    data: []
  }

  getData = () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        return setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(
            [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: "Kelas A",
                list: ["Jane", "Ali", "Ahmad"]
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                name: "Kelas B",
                list: ["May", "Henry", "Ben"]
              }
            ]
          )
        },500)
      })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })

    const data = await this.getData()
    this.setState({
      data,
      loading: false
    })
  }

  //loadingComponent = () => <div>Loading...</div>;

  render() {

    const { data, loading } = this.state

    return (
      <Tabs 
        activeTab={1} 
        loading={loading} 
        //loadingComponent={this.loadingComponent()}
      >
        {data.map(o => (
          <Tab 
            id={o.id}            
          >
            <Tab.Title>{o.name}</Tab.Title>
            <Tab.Content>
              {o.list.join(", ")}
            </Tab.Content>
          </Tab>
        ))}
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

I pass loading state as prop to Tabs children component, it worked, I can see true and false:

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    activeTab: 1
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.loading !== prevState.loading){
      return {
        loading: nextProps.loading
      }
    }
  }

  state = {
    activeTab: this.props.activeTab
  };

  changeTab = tab => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: tab });
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { activeTab, loading } = this.state;

    console.log('true or false before pass to children', loading)

    return (
      <div className="tabs">
        {React.Children.map(children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, {
            loading,
            activeTab,
            changeTab: this.changeTab
          })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I pass that loading as prop to Tabs's children which is Tab, the loading flag became just false? I can't spot the problem.

```
class Tab extends Component {
  static Title = ({ children, tabId, activeTab, handleTabClick }) => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`title ${tabId === activeTab ? "active" : ""}`}
        onClick={handleTabClick}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };

  static Content = ({ children, tabId, activeTab, loading }) => {

    loading && 'Loading...' //won't work coz loading is always false, I wonder why

    return tabId === activeTab ? (
      <div className="content">{children}</div>
    ) : null;
  };

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        handleTabClick: () => this.props.changeTab(this.props.id),
        tabId: this.props.id,
        activeTab: this.props.activeTab,
        loading: this.props.loading // why always false?
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**My demo**
https://codesandbox.io/s/o41r35n2qz

Comment: no one can answer this?

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.loading` is always `false` in your child component because it does not even get rendered when it's `true`, as `data` is empty when `loading` is `true` so `data.map` does not create any components.

You would need to move the loading check to a parent component that is rendered even when `data` is empty. Eg. https://codesandbox.io/s/xpy3r3575z

EDIT:
If you want to fetch the data separately for each tab, then you need to create separate API calls, one for fetching tab titles to render the tab headers, and one for fetching the data for the active tab.

Comment: this load the entire table which is not what I want, I want to load the tab content when user switching tab.

Comment: Then you need to use react-router or some tabs library that supports that, or alter your `Tabs` implementation to render only the active tab.

Comment: So are you expecting to see `Loading...` even time you switch tab, even after the data has been fetched? You fetched the data for all the tabs at once, so I'm not sure what you are expecting to see. Do you intend to fetch the data separately for each tab?

Comment: In that case you need multiple API calls. Added some details to post.

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you set it as false

```
state = {
    loading: false,
    data: []
  }
```

When the component has been loaded you simulate it to true and then false

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true 
    })

    const data = await this.getData()
    this.setState({
      data,
      loading: false
    })
  }
```

But you never received component state changes in child components.

You can get changes of a state using [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html)

So you can give it a try as

```
class Tab extends Component {

 componentWillReceiveProps(props) { //here you will get changes whenever state changes
   let loading  = props.loading
   this.setState({loading});
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        handleTabClick: () => this.props.changeTab(this.props.id),
        tabId: this.props.id,
        activeTab: this.props.activeTab,
        loading: this.state.loading //through state
      })
    );
  }
}
```